# The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect (Python/ Pyinstaller/ Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I programmed a small application and compiled it using pyinstaller. However I can't run my compiled .exe. It shows this error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it and create a working .exe?

**pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon " "**

Comment: Why did you compile it into an exe?

Comment: You should follow the advice in the message to gather more information.

Comment: @AaronCloud that is kind of a silly question, what if they want to distribute it? just practice? there are at least a few reasons

Comment: @Matiiss no not really. If they have a goal in mind, there are different ways of achieving it. Knowing why they are compiling it into an exe, which adds a layer of complicity, might help us figure out a different solution.

Comment: @AaronCloud bcz I needed to run it without python in another pc.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. For me it turned out to be a bug related to pyinstaller 4.7 and python 3.9.8. I uninstalled python 3.9.8 and installed 3.9.5 instead and it worked perfectly with pyinstaller -w, my exe file runs without a console window now, and without any errors.

Comment: i found using 3.9.7 works too

Comment: @mariusghinea I used Python 3.9.8 and, my pyinstaller version is 4.6. Does it sound like I want to install Python 3.9.8 and Pyinstaller 4.7 or other pyinstaller version.

Comment: try versions combinations of Python and pyinstaller and you should find one that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of --windowed argument in Windows. Without it it compiles and works ok, but you need to keep the Command Prompt window open too. Still trying to find a work-around.

Comment: yes. when I compiled it without --windowed argument. it works successfully